# I want to show ads at beginning in page ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I want to show ads at beginning in page ViewController.

I using this code on google admob but I try that on simulator but without show ads.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.load(request)
        if interstitial.isReady {
            interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to show ads on simulator or anything device I have
but this code above not work I don't know why this code not work

Comment: The line `interstitial.load(request)` seems to be an asynchronous request, try asking  `if interstitial.isReady` within a completion handler.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can call isReady right after load, you'd have to wait a bit.
Probably best to use the delegate to know for sure.

> "This is best to do several seconds before the interstitial is needed to preload its content."
>   ~[**GoogleMobileAds Framework Reference: GADInterstitial** Documentation](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADInterstitial)

Comment: <Google>[I-ACS037005] Unable to fetch effective App ID from identity

Comment: Looks like you're still just calling isReady right after calling load.
Not sure why you would downvote my answer as it is not inaccurate.
You could simply ask clarifying questions if you need more information.

Thanks @ejderuby for the edit.

Comment: please anyone help me